# MathJax and Latex Syntax Checker - Copy and Paste Code

Tags: editors, mathjax, proofreading, syntax-checker

Please pardon me if this is be a duplicate which I would be fain to delete. Please feel free to edit this post and tags.

I'm seeking a syntax checker (preferably free) for Latex and MathJax and etc, that allows TEX code to be copied and pasted directly thereinto. This checker shouldn't require code to be typed in another Latex program. If necessary, it could parse a saved PDF or Notepad or Word file in which I wrote the Tex code. Please let me know if this answers the question of "static program analysis"?

This program would then divulge and signalise all errors and problems.

Would the programs in [Is there a program equivalent to lint for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163/is-there-a-program-equivalent-to-lint-for-latex) suit the above?

Comment: Are you talking about static analysis of TeX/LaTeX code?

Comment: You may be able to use an online editor to do so for you—they usually have some sort of error management system.  Static analysis is, however, strictly impossible due to TeX's Turing-completeness.

Comment: @Jubobs: Thanks for the comment. I updated my OP about "static program analysis," but I'm not too acquainted with this term. Does it help and answer your question?

Comment: @SeanAllred: Thank you. Where could I find these online editors? A Google search produces only desktop programs whose ability to do the above is unknown to me?

Comment: https://www.writelatex.com/ and https://www.sharelatex.com/‎ are nice examples of online editors.

Answer (score 2):

As noted before, a true syntax checker for LaTeX (or any other TeX format) is [strictly impossible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis#Formal_methods) due to [TeX's Turing-completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX#Typesetting_system). However, you can find the most common errors with the [`lacheck`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/lacheck) script, included in your TeX distribution.

Comment: In addition to `lacheck`, whose development is dead years ago, I'd suggest [`ChkTeX`](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/chktex/).