# Is there a way to impose/automate coding style?

Tags: texstudio, coding

I am wondering if there is a way to  *impose* coding style in editors (TeXstudio etc.), or to get it automatically formatted, in order to have always code as clean as in C or Python, for instance.

Comment: Have a look here → https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163/is-there-a-program-equivalent-to-lint-for-latex

Comment: Perhaps relevent: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26102/latex-code-sniffer-and-or-beautifier

Comment: Thanks both. So, the 1st is more for syntax error. The 2nd seems more related, but, if I understood correctly, latexindent.pl is a script one has to run externally (maybe it could be attached to the compilation workflow...) ... I am looking more for a package that can be simply loaded at the beginning of your .tex ...

Comment: Have you looked at arara? It sounds like it might be of interest. It contains a rule for latexindent. If you find a script that can be loaded in the way you describe, do let me know :) disclaimer: I'm the author of latexindent