# Restricting commands

Tags: macros

I have a class file that is used by my students to create their final year project reports. The class imposes a style and limits the number of pages the students can write.

However, there is nothing that prevents students from using commands to change indentation, line spacing etc.

I guess, my question is: is there a class of commands that can all be disabled as being "low level"

Comment: Not really, and everything you impose can be overwritten.

Comment: You can un-define such commands (or define them to throw an error), like `\let\parindent\@undefined`. But it will be hard to hunt all of them (TeX's primitives plus LaTeX's commands, plus possible packages), and it's most likely it will break something. Also this will take effect after the `\documentclass`, so if they really want to they can do something before that. A "you shall not pass" kind of warning might work better.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik er after `\let\parindent\@undefined` then every `\centering` or `\raggedright` or `\parbox` or `minipage` or tabular `p` column and every itemize or enumerate list would give an error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's why I said it will most likely break something. Of course "most likely" is an euphemism :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX is a macro expansion language. Definitions are not like functions in a compiled language where the implementation details are hidden and underlying commands can be changed without affecting the defined commands.

The definitions are simply expanded in place with each macro being replaced by its replacement text until a primitive is encountered.

That means that you can not disable specifying paragraph indentation (for example) without disabling every command (lists, section heads, ....) that uses `\parindent` internally.

The above isn't quite true, there are always things you can do, (for example your class could define section commands to locally restore the original definitions) but it is near enough true to mean that disabling this at the technical level is not possible. You have to enforce the house style by social means (or administrative control) not via TeX definitions.

Comment: I guess the only "technical" possibility would be to create a program that checks the content of the tex file before passing it to LaTeX.  I will have a look at [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163/is-there-a-program-equivalent-to-lint-for-latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163/is-there-a-program-equivalent-to-lint-for-latex).

Comment: @Pierre any student at all familiar with tex could defeat any such linter  try to check this file for disallowed commands https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/contrib/xii

Comment: I did not realise that so many birds and people could be fitted in so little space :)